# Is merging Feature and Request specs supported rspec behavior?

Tags: rspec

I was recently building out a feature spec inside "spec/features", and in the middle of the feature spec, I decided to try doing this

```
context "foo", type: :request do
  it "works" do
    get some_path
    expect(response.body).to eq("something")
    visit some_path
    expect(page).to have_content("something")
  end
end
```

To my astonishment, it actually worked.  Typically in a feature spec, you can't cal the `get`, `post`, etc... methods and in a request spec you can't call the capybara `visit` method.  It works the other way as well.  If I'm in a request spec inside "spec/requests", I can tag things with :feature and get the same behavior.

Is this supported rspec behavior?  I understand there may be design/conceptual problems with this, but are there technical downside to co-mingling the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why what we now know as feature specs and request specs are split out into separate directories is outlined in [this blog post](http://www.andylindeman.com/rspec-rails-and-capybara-2.0-what-you-need-to-know/).

In summary, though, splitting them out was done in Capybara 2.0 to alleviate confusion of having a single kind of spec, the `request` spec, be responsible for performing full-stack integration tests *as well as* high-level specs that would drive the application only using its external interface (usually done via a headless web browser).  So, the current generally-agreed structure of specs would be:

- Put anything that uses the Capybara DSL (`visit` etc) to assert on a `page` object in `spec/features`
- Put full-stack non-controller specs that use Rack DSL (`get` etc) to assert on a `response` object in `spec/requests`

It's probably best not to co-mingle the two if you can, even though it's possible, if for no other reason than to keep with convention and give your future colleagues less surprises.

---

As for *why* you can co-mingle the specs if you want to, it's mostly to do with RSpec configuration, so it is supported behaviour:

- You will likely have the line `config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!` in your `rails_helper.rb` somewhere, which means that RSpec will consider any files in `spec/features` to be feature specs and any files in `spec/requests` to be request specs
- Therefore, even if you wrap a `type: :request` flag around a spec in the `spec/features` folder, hence giving that single spec access to the Rack DSL, it will *still* have access to the Capybara DSL

You could even use `RSpec.config` to allow the Capybara DSL into any spec type or directory path you wanted, though this is [not recommended](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-rails/file/Capybara.md#Upgrading_to_Capybara-2_0):

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Capybara::DSL, type: :request
  config.include Capybara::DSL, file_path: %r{spec/requests}
end
```

Overall though, for the sake of your codebase, future you, and your future colleagues, it's probably best to try and keep everything in its right place.

Comment: Thanks for the great info.

Comment: since the link is no longer valid - https://web.archive.org/web/20150302031543/http://www.andylindeman.com:80/rspec-rails-and-capybara-2.0-what-you-need-to-know